# How to merge two MySQL databases

Tags: mysql

I set up a database a few months ago as a bit of an experiment and it sits happily on my hard drive having been set up with Homebrew.

Then a few days ago I was looking at a project and remembered MAMP as an option to provide a localised service. I installed and I have the situation where phpMyAdmin points at a new database.

I'm left with a situation where I can login by CLI to the old database when what I really want is MAMP to point to that database so I can do some admin work with PHPMyAdmin rather than the one I've just created. Can I just merge both the Homebrew and MAMP set ups?

If it sounds like I'm very new to this, yes, I am.

Comment: Simply copy the data from old DB to new one saving the referential relations.

Comment: But copy the entire tree, not must one "database".  Better yet, look for the setting that configures where that tree is.

Comment: The title talks about "merging"; the discussion talks about "moving".  Which is it?